# Cross Platform: How to set a distinct incremented Build Number in UWP and keep the Version Name like in iOS/Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, windows-store-apps, version, versioning, xamarin.uwp

I am developing an App Cross-Platform for iOS, Android and UWP and I have trouble keeping the versions in sync.
iOS and Android use a build number and a version name.
[Android Versioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O98wN.png)
[iOS Versioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf6lN.png)
I can upload several builds with the same version name for testing and just increment the build number and then release the final version.
Customers only see the version name.

UWP only has the name, three numbers (major, minor, build) and you have to increment every time you upload to the store, making it impossible to test version 4.1.2, make some small changes and then release it, you'd have to count up to 4.1.3
[UWP Versioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EshI5.png)

BUT when creating App Packages, they give you a 4. place in the  version name, but it is disabled.
[create App Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SOqO.png)

Is there any way to use a build number system like in iOS/Android for UWP releases?

Any hack/Workaround helps as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be impossible to use a build number system like in ios/andriod for UWP releases.

You provide must have a version number for each package when you upload the package to the Store.For Windows UWP packages, the last (fourth) section of the version number is reserved for Store use and must be left as 0 when you build your package (although the Store may change the value in this section). The other sections must be set to an integer between 0 and 65535 (except for the first section, which cannot be 0).

You could get more information in the document:[Package version numbering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/package-version-numbering)

Partner Center gives you several options([beta testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/beta-testing-and-targeted-distribution)) to let testers try out your app before you offer it to the public.